# Как сделать такое выражение? На ЯваСкрипте

Tags: математика, javascript

Допустим, есть значение равное 500 (оно может быть любым), ныжно сделать так, чтобы была такая формула:
((Значение+1000)*2)+30% = результат.

Помогите пожалуйста как такое реализовать. Без алертов желательно

Answer (score 1):

```
<input type='text' id='value'>

var elem = document.getElementById('value');

elem.onchange = function() {
    var value = parseFloat(document.getElementById('value').value);
    var result = ((value+1000)*2)+value * .3;

    console.log(result);
    //alert(result);
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/f9JJS/